# Let $G$ a graph of order $n$. Prove that $n\leq \mathcal{X}(G) \mathcal{X}(\overline{G})$ and $2\sqrt{n}\leq \mathcal{X}(G)+\mathcal{X}(\overline{G})$

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G$, the $\textit{chromatic number}$ of $G$, denoted by $\mathcal{X}(G)$, is the smallest integer $k$ such that $G$ is $k-$colorable.

$\textbf{Problem.}$ Let $G$ a graph of order $n$. Prove that

$1.$  $n\leq \mathcal{X}(G) \mathcal{X}(\overline{G})$.

$2.$  $2\sqrt{n}\leq \mathcal{X}(G)+\mathcal{X}(\overline{G})$.

Note: $\overline{G}$ it's the complement of $G$.

I was trying for the second part about it problem to use AM-GM and first part. I was able to test the first part of the problem, but how could I prove the second part of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second part of the problem immediately follows from AM-GM and the first part, since
$$\sqrt{n} \leq \sqrt{\chi(G) \chi(\bar G)} = GM \leq AM =\frac{\chi(G) + \chi(\bar G)}{2}$$

The first part in my opinion is slightly more challenging. To see why this is, note that if $\chi(G) = k$, then the vertices of $G$ can be divided into $k$ independent sets. Furthermore, one of these independent sets has size at least $n / k$. The vertices in any such independent set become a clique of size at least $n / k$ in $\bar G$. But the chromatic number of a clique is the number of vertices, so the chromatic number of $\bar G$ must be at least $n / k$. It then follows that $\chi(\bar G) \geq n / \chi(G) \iff \chi(G) \chi(\bar G) \geq n$.

Comment: For the first part simply observe that, if $f:V(G)\to C$ is a proper coloring of $G$ with $|C|=\chi(G)$, and if $g:V(G)\to D$ is a proper coloring of $\overline G$ with $|D|=\chi(\overline G)$, then $v\mapsto(f(v),g(v))$ is an injective mapping from $V(G)$ to $C\times D$, showing that $n=|V(G)|\le|C\times D|=\chi(G)\chi(\overline G)$.